# How to separate view from viewcontroller using storyboard swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, subclass, loadview

Practicing MVC pattern and want to separate view from viewcontroller using storyboard.

in main.storyboard I have a viewcontroller, and there are some uilabels in rootview.

to separate view code from viewcontroller, I selected view from viewcontroller scene , created FruitDetailView class and subclassed it in storyboard identity inspector.

[image]

[image]

And connected UILabels to FruitDetailView class.

```
class FruitDetailView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var type: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        name.text = ""
        type.text = ""
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func update(_ detail: Fruit) {
        name.text = detail.name
        type.text = detail.type
    }
    
}
```

In the viewController , created FruitDetailView() instance.
And in loadview() methods, assigned fruitDetailView instance to view property.

```
class FruitDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let fruitDetailView = FruitDetailViewController()
    var fruit = Fruit()
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = fruitDetailView
        fruitDetailView.update(fruit)
    }

}
```

But when I run the app, app crashes with error.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Initialize name.text and type.text in awakeFromNib() rather than init(frame:)

Comment: @RobertCrabtree if I initialize those properties in awakeFromNib() , no errors. but it shows only black view and I can not see any labels.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different problem. Did you constrain your labels? What happens if you change the background color of your view?

Comment: I set uilabel's constraints in storyboard. if I change background color to white, I see only white view.

Comment: Are you sure the text in your textFields aren't empty strings

Comment: I have no textFields in my view. first I want to set those labels to empty string like " ". then update when I want.

Comment: Sorry I meant label, not textField. You aren't going to see your label if they don't have any text

Comment: I know that. I also tried to set label's text with some string values but same result.. can see only white background

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you want to reach your FruitDetail class created before even its properties being created. Put a breakpoint to the `name.text = ""` and run and you will see what i mean. To solve this just control your nil value safely :

```
if let label = name { // by the way consider in future to assign values like nameLabel rather than name
    name.text = "put your string value"
}
```